# Creating multiple dropdowns dependent on one dropdown in jQuery

Tags: c#, html, jquery, select, dropdown

how can I have several drop-downs that depend on one drop-down, for example, by changing the value of the first drop-down, the values ​​of the rest of the drop-downs will be filtered

The code I wrote is as follows

```
IEnumerable<LessonsGroupViewModel> LessonGroupAndSubGroups = ViewBag.LessonGroup;
            <select name="ParentId" id="ParentId" class="form-select form-control">
                @foreach (var group in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(p => p.ParentId == null))
                {
                    <option value="@group.ID" name="@group.ID">@group.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>
            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>

            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>
            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>
            <select class="form-select form-control" name="GroupId" id="GroupId">
                @foreach (var subGroup in LessonGroupAndSubGroups.Where(i => i.ParentId != null))
                {
                    <option value="@subGroup.GroupName" name="@subGroup.ParentId">@subGroup.GroupName</option>
                }
            </select>

var $select1 = $("#ParentId"),
    $select2 = $("#GroupId"),
    $options = $select2.find('option');

$select1.on('change', function () {
    $select2.html($options.filter('[name="' + this.value + '"]'));
}).trigger('change');
enter code here
enter code here
```

This code works fine for one dropdown, but it doesn't work for more than one dropdown. I also tried the class and tag selector, but it didn't work.
It is very important to solve this problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I hope this will assist you
Credit: Alvaro Montoro
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30348221/22672978

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript jQuery dependent drop down list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346640/javascript-jquery-dependent-drop-down-list)